# Ruby transformation to merge an Array of Hashes into another Array of Hash?

Tags: ruby

I have

```
 [
   {:date => "2012-05", :post => 1}, 
   {:date => "2012-12", :post => 1}, 
   {:date => "2013-02", :post => 1}, 
   {:date => "2012-05", :online => 1}
 ]
```

And I want to get:

```
[
  {:date => "2012-05", :post => 1, :online => 1}, 
  {:date => "2012-12", :post => 1 }, 
  {:date => "2013-02", :post => 1 }
]
```

Anyone sees how to apply Ruby hash/array methods to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks for the great answers! I hope to summarize some of my insights on this in a small blog post soon. Didn't know too much about the power of group_by and inject.

Comment: I have tried to summarize some of my learnings here: http://thinkingonthinking.com/map-reduce-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it via [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) and [`detect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
arr = [
        {:date => "2012-05", :post => 1}, 
        {:date => "2012-12", :post => 1}, 
        {:date => "2013-02", :post => 1}, 
        {:date => "2012-05", :online => 1}
      ]

arr.inject([]) do |new_array, a|

  # if there is an existing hash in the new array with the same date
  # merge the values
  #
  if existing = new_array.detect{ |b| a[:date] == b[:date] } 
    existing.merge!(a)
  else
    new_array << a
  end

  # always return the new array for new iteration
  #
  new_array
end
```

Comment: wow... very cool, I need to understand better the inject... thanks!

Comment: Note that the use of `detect` inside of `inject` converts a O(n) problem to O(n^2).

Comment: @tokland Interesting thought, but how come? If any, detect would render the problem O(2n), but it is not duplicating objects, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: I mean complexity in time. Look at it this way: inject is O(n), detect is also O(n). Since they are nested, it makes the complete algorithm O(n^2) in the worst case.

Comment: @tokland ok, get it. What is `group_by` then? O(n log n)?

Comment: No, O(n log n) usually results when sorting, `group_by` is just an accumulator, so it's O(n) in time.

Comment: @tokland ok, thanks for that lesson. Seems I have to learn more about that :) Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 6):

```
q.group_by { |x| x[:date] }.values.map { |e| e.reduce :merge }
```

Answer (score 3):

Functional approach:

```
items_by_date = items.group_by { |h| h[:date] }
result = items_by_date.map { |date, hs| hs.reduce(:merge) }
```

Comment: @DigitalRoss: You're welcome :-) To keep it slightly different I've mapped directly over the grouped hash and used an intermediate variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one attempt:

```
a = {:date=>"2012-05", :post=>1}, {:date=>"2012-12", :post=>1}, {:date=>"2013-02", :post=>1}
b = {:date=>"2012-05", :online=>1}

ar = {}; [a, b].flatten.each do |k|
  c = k.first[1]; ar[c] ||= Array.new
  ar[c] << { k.to_a.last[0] => k.to_a.last[1] }
end

ar.map { |k,v| { k => v[1] ? v[0].merge(v[1]) : v[0] } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = [
   {:date => "2012-05", :post => 1}, 
   {:date => "2012-12", :post => 1}, 
   {:date => "2013-02", :post => 1}, 
   {:date => "2012-05", :online => 1}
 ]

hash.group_by{ |h| h[:date] }.values.map{ |x| x.reduce(:merge) }
=> [{:date=>"2012-05", :post=>1, :online=>1},
    {:date=>"2012-12", :post=>1},
    {:date=>"2013-02", :post=>1}]
```

Comment: isn't the same that @DigitalRoss'?

Comment: actually yes, I was writing my answer too long.